# .fadeIn() Black Outline IE6, 7, 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

So i have a DIV with some text in and for some reason with a fadeIn call IE renders a black outline around the text

Here is a screenshot and a link to a fiddle for an example;

http://jsfiddle.net/JNaEV/!

[Black IE Border Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLrar.jpg)

Comment: @Xavier:  It has to do with how IE turns off font-smoothing during animation... [See this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444756/font-family-renders-poorly-in-explorer-with-jquery-animation)

Comment: @Xavier - the similar problem is also at least in FF 3.6.17, see [here](http://i55.tinypic.com/2ujkopz.jpg). Instead of black you can see cyan.

Comment: @Sparky672 so just to confirm you have:

`<div id="one"> <-- fade this div
   <div id="text">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</div>
</div>`

Comment: @Daemon_X more problems lol! must be something to do with filtering :/

Comment: @Xavier:  Yes, that fixed it for me in my project.

Comment: @Xavier - I've been looking on the net for a while and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457929/jquery-toggle-function-rendering-weird-text-in-ie-losing-cleartype/457940#457940). It works fine in IE and FF but I'm wondering why it's not already solved in new jQuery version. Here is the [demo](http://malsup.com/jquery/fadetest.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE disables font antialiasing while it does opacity animations...

[Font-family renders poorly in Explorer with jQuery animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444756/font-family-renders-poorly-in-explorer-with-jquery-animation)

I fixed mine by placing everything inside a container DIV and applying the jQuery fades & animations to the container instead of the text element itself.

Comment: well i tried this:

`<div id="text">
     <div class="data">
     It's time to put talent at <br />the heart of your business.
        </div>
    </div>`

Yet it had no effect